# Android GSON convert error - Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, json, gson, converters, retrofit

everybody. 
I have a situation when my object that I'm receiving from server can be in multiple types. It could be an empty ArrayList or some Object type with filled values, depends on different situations.

That is why I get an GSON error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                              at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:161)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                           Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 360 path $.user_fields
```

So, the final question is how to construct object right on client side to convert the response from server in simplest way with GSON lib?

Comment: It's expecting an object but your response is returning array

Comment: right, but I get an empty array, when is no object, another case, when server has an info, it respond me an object

Comment: how you parse the json? Add code. Why the server response an empty array? Why not an empty object?

Comment: Suppose it is an array try to decode it as an array if it fails, try to decode it as an object. You need two try catch blocks.